# -f command not found

Tags: execute-command

```
echo"enter first file"
read file
echo"enter second file"
read file1
if [-f $ file]
then
    if[-f $file1]
    then
        cmp $file $file1
        if [$? -eq u]
        then rm $file1
            echo"both are same"
            echo"deleted second file"
        else
            echo"files are not similar"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

1. List item

Comment: i am unable to solve this error

Comment: The `[` and `]` test operators need white space around them: `[ -f "$file" ]` and so on

Comment: i've changed it...it is showing the same old error

Comment: `if [-f $ file]` what is that supposed to do?  `if [ -f $file ]`

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to be careful about blank space between words in shell scripts. The problem with `[` was already mentioned in the comments, but you have some other problems, too - the `$ file` and also `echo"stuff` with no space.

Also, you have some other problems. In case the filename contains a space, you should use quotes with all `"$variable"` references. I don't know why you thought `u` would work in `if [$? -eq u]` - the value will be 0, not u.